# How do I determine the graph of functions involving radicals?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials

What is the explanation behind:

- the graph of $h(x)=\sqrt{4-x^2}$ is the upper half of the graph of $x^2+y^2=4$
- the graph of $g(x)=-\sqrt{2-x}$ is the lower branch of the parabola $x=2-y^2$

I kind of get it, but I want to know the algorithm of getting to that conclusion.

Comment: Squaring both sides of $$y=\sqrt{4-x^2}$$ gives you $y^2=4-x^2$, or equivalently $x^2+y^2=4$. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{x}$ is the principal (non-negative) square root of $x$.  Hence, $h(x) = \sqrt{4 - x^2} \geq 0$, so it represents the upper half of the circle, while $g(x) = -\sqrt{2 - x} \leq 0$, so it represents the lower half of the parabola.

Comment: @Crostul Hi! Yeah, I get it now. So essentially, the graphs of rad functions are parts of quadratic functions w/c you can derive from the rad functions. Thanks.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For the **first question**, the function can actually be written as:

$$y=\sqrt{4-x^2} \Rightarrow y^2=4-x^2 \Rightarrow x^2+y^2=4$$

Hence the given function is a part of the circle $x^2+y^2=4$.

Since given equation has $y \geq 0$ (by convention, square root is considered positive) , so it refers to the upper half of the circle.

2. For the **second question**, the function can actually be written as:

$$y=-\sqrt{2-x} \Rightarrow y^2=2-x \Rightarrow x=2-y^2$$

Hence the given function is a part of the curve $x=2-y^2$.

Since given equation has $y \leq 0$ (by convention, square root is considered positive and the negative sign is before it) , so it refers to the lower half of the curve.

Comment: In the first question, $y \geq 0$; in the second question, $y \leq 0$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks. Typo corrected.